# Doctrine 2 - Retrieving the lastest record from history table

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Using a `status_history` table that will save the date and time a status was modified for a particular record in `entries`, I'm trying to find the easiest way to also get the current status, AKA, the status with the lastest date.

For instance consider the following: `status_history`

```
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | entry_id |   status   | timestamp |
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |        1 | Processing | 15:05:09  |
|  2 |        1 | In Review  | 15:05:18  |
|  3 |        1 | Complete   | 15:05:26  |
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
```

And of course, our entry: `entries`

```
+----+--------+
| id | title  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Foobar |
+----+--------+
```

How can I retrieve, **with DQL**,  the the latest status (technically the current status) for a particular entry, **without having to maintain a `latest_status_id` column** in my `Entry` entity?

Consider the call `$entry->getCurrentStatus()` would return `"Complete"`. However, in the case we have a great amount of status records for that entry, a second query to load all statuses might turn into a performance drop.

**NOTE:** In [this article](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html) they describe it with the extra column approach, using a locking mechanism for concurrency. I'd like to avoid this approach unless this is the correct one, since we're trying not to have double relations for each table (`status_history.entry_id` and `entry.latest_history_id`).

Comment: how do you fetch the `$entry`?

Comment: Using DQL of course. However, the query itself is what I'm trying to figure out since the idea is that it also brings the last row for it's status.

Comment: if the query is what you're trying to figure out I'd recommend adding it to the post. Might lower barrier for people to chime in with help or nudge in the right direction

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: - Do you want to retrieve the entry and status_history in the same query?  
- Do you retrieve multiple entries in the first query?  
- Do you want to retrieve whole entities or just fields?

Comment: I want to retrieve the entry and the lastest status.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco can you provide me with answers to the other questions as well?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I want to retrieve the `entry` entity, along with the record that correspond to the latest status history. Not necessarily in 1 query, but emulating eager loading, in the way that I don't have to load 1 by 1 all the history records and loop through them. Can be in both cases: retrieving multiple entries and retrieving a single entry. Retrieving the whole entity would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

For a single entry the query could look something like this:

```php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e, s 
    FROM entries e 
    JOIN e.status_history s 
    WHERE e.entry_id = :entry_id
    ORDER BY s.timestamp DESC');
$query->setParameter('entry_id', $entry_id);
$entries = $query->getSingleResult();
```

In your `getCurrentStatus()` method you can return the only status_history object that is assigned.

For all entries it is more complex and you have to use a subquery with `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`. It is feasible in native SQL but I haven't figured out how to do it with DQL. I will update my answer as soon as I've got a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a `QueryBuilder` inside your status history repository this would be sufficient:

```
$entry_id = 1;
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('s')
    ->where('s.entry = :entry_id')
    ->orderBy('o.id', 'DESC')
    ->setParameter('entry_id', $entry_id)
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
return $query->getSingleResult();
```

You can use id assuming that id is "auto increment" and the `timestamp` is an automatic time-stamp of creation of your records. In such case highest id is always the latest insert, so you don't even need to use the `timestamp` column to find that record.

Otherwise you have to add an index to your `timestamp` column and order by that column instead:

```
$entry_id = 1;
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('s')
    ->where('s.entry = :entry_id')
    ->orderBy('o.timestamp', 'DESC')
    ->setParameter('entry_id', $entry_id)
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
return $query->getSingleResult();
```

You need to add an index to your `timestamp` column for increased performance

Comment: shouldn't you order by timestamp instead of id?

Comment: It depends. It might not even be necessary. Please read the comment under the answer.